# MongoDB Count By Current Month

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I'm new to MongoDB. I need to get the count of the posts which are posted in this current month. PlateModel is my model I've kept timestamps true also. It looks like the below:

```
  { timestamps: true }
```

My present code in the Controller looks like below:

```
 const today = new Date();
    const host_count = await PlateModel.find({
      $and: [
        {
          postedBy: req.user._id,
        },
        {
          createdAt: today.getMonth(),
        },
      ],
    }).count();
```

But, I get the count value 0. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the objects from the start of the current month to the end of the next month:

```
const startOfCurrentMonth = new Date();
startOfCurrentMonth.setDate(1);

const startOfNextMonth = new Date();
startOfNextMonth.setDate(1);
startOfNextMonth.setMonth(startOfNextMonth.getMonth() + 1);

const host_count = await PlateModel.find({
  $and: [
    {
      postedBy: req.user._id,
    },
    {
      createdAt: {
          $gte: startOfCurrentMonth,
          $lt: startOfNextMonth
      }
    },
  ],
}).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Moment** library.

```
const moment = require("moment");

const firstdate = moment().startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(firstdate);

const lastdate=moment().endOf('month').format("DD-MM-YYYY"); 
console.log(lastdate);

 
const host_count = await PlateModel.find({
  $and: [
    {
      postedBy: req.user._id,
    },
    {
      createdAt: {
          $gte:firstdate,
          $lt:lastdate
      }
    },
  ],
}).count();
```